# Is it necessary to include the /run directory in backups?

Tags: linux, backup, directory, exclude

I use a variant of the simple script below from the [Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR) described

```
tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/sys --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/dev /
```

I used it again on Ubuntu 12.04 and I saw some files from the /run being skipped by the script. Should the /run directory be added to the excluded directories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No sure on Ubuntu 12.04 but, on Arch Linux /run is a tmpfs and on my Ubuntu 12.04 where only /var/run exists it is also a tmpfs. So if it is a tmpfs, what I assume, on 12.04 then you can exclude it.

Answer (score 3):

Exclude it. The standard set of directories that I exclude in Linux backup processes are:

```
/dev
/lost+found
/media
/misc
/mnt
/net
/proc
/sys
```

and *maybe* `/var/run`